# Proxy issue in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to run SPFX project in my office environment. Internet is using proxy to restrict internet access so I am getting below error while running npm command.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to solve it using below code.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy aa.zz.yy.xx:abcd
npm config set https-proxy aa.zz.yy.xx:abcd
npm config set proxy aa.zz.yy.xx:abcd
npm set strict-ssl false
```

But still getting same error...

Comment: Even I couldn't resolve this error. Network policies changed in my organisation, since then started getting these errors. For time being I have been creating new webparts at home and then continuing my work with them in office next day.